# Flash always appears on top in google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm building a popup window. I use an iframe to cover backgroud content then show a div over this iframe to show popup content.

In the background page I have a YouTube video embedded, code sample:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2XY3AvVgDns" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

My problem: The YouTube video always shows on top and covers my popup window.

Note: My code works fine on IE and FireFox, but not GoogleChrome

How can I let my popup window show on top in GoogleChrome?

Comment: may be you might need to add styles that will only apply to chrome. check this may help you http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the url to:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/2XY3AvVgDns?wmode=transparent
```

Notice the `?wmode=transparent` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `visibility` style property of the `<iframe>` element to `hidden` should help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify your iframe to object. If yes, try using 
    <param wmode="transparent"></param>

Hopefully it should work.